# What's the probability that at least one of k top data still appears in top k positions of a data set with error?

Tags: probability

Let {${d_1,d_2,d_3,..., d_k,...d_n}$} is a descendingly sorted data set.

Now we suppose that each data in the set has a probability $p_e$ to go wrong. 
The problem is what's the probability that at least one element of {${d_1,d_2,d_3,...,d_k}$}
will be still in the top $k$ positions?

Generally, $n>>k$, and we assume that $d_i$ is uniformly distributed over [0，1] and its wrong value is with the same distribution.

This problem is not very simple. I have got a good result for $p_e>1/2$:
$$1-{p_e}^k-(1-p_e)*{p_e}^{2k-1}*{e^k}/\sqrt{2kπ}$$.
It seems that there is a complex relation in this problem. But I have no better solution for arbitrary $p_e$.

Moreover, I have got an approximate result for arbitrary $p_e$ as 
$$1-{[\frac {p_e(n-k)} n]}^k-(1-{p_e}^k)\sum_{i=k}^{n-k}
[\binom{n-k}{i} {p_e}^i{(1-p_e)}^{n-k-i}\binom{i}{k}{(\frac {k}{n})}^k
{(1-\frac k n)}^{(i-k)}]$$

The error of this formula is about 10% not satisfactory for me，so a much better one is expected.

Recently I have got a good result as follows:
$$1-{[\frac {p_e(n-k)} n]}^k-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\{{p_e}^{i-1}(1-{p_e})
\sum_{j=k}^{n-k}[\binom{n-k}{j} {p_e}^j{(1-p_e)}^{n-k-j}
\sum_{m=k}^{j}\binom{j}{m}{(\frac {i}{n})}^m{(1-\frac i n)}^{(j-m)}]\}$$

This result has an error of about 7‰, which seems acceptable. However, it is also so complicated that we want a much more simple form of it.

Comment: Presumably the errors occur before the data is sorted.  If $d_1$ doesn't have an error, the only way it can fail to be in the first $k$ is if $k$ of the error terms are larger.  Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: Yes,that is what I want.